# Serva boot 0x56 wrong username or password error

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, windows-installation

maybe its not question but I was wondering how to fix it.

If you can not log in to last step of installation, you need to create new local account on your PC which provides server and then use username and password of this local account.
Simple but I couldnt find out how it works :) so heres how to do it:

serva install and setup:
[serva setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvCXb8a4M_o)

and heres how to create local acc:
[local acc how to do it](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how%20to%20create%20users%20in%20windows%2010%20site:microsoft.com&form=B00032&ocid=SettingsHAQ-BingIA&mkt=en-US)

Enjoy :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really a question.